# 4 rocker light switch makes a popping noise, and I've noticed it a few times when the Air conditioning clicks on? Thank you. Kind of worried

Tags: electrical, air-conditioning

My master bathroom 4 rocker light switch makes a "Pop" noise several times a day. Tonight, I think it popped when the air conditioning went on(yes air conditioning :) Could have been a coincidence though. The air handler is in the attic in another room. Is this a matter of changing the light switch out, or ? My biggest fear of course is a fire,especially when not home because of my animals. I appreciate any help,advice etc. Thank you

Comment: Can you post a photo of the switch box please?

Comment: Sure,thank you! New on here. Trying to figure out how to. Hold on please